# How can I use a forked version of Laravel 4.2 in composer.json?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I forked the 'laravel/framework' library into my own Github account, and made a small change on the 4.2 branch. Here's a link to my version:

https://github.com/flyingL123/framework/tree/4.2

I followed the instructions on composer's website to update composer.json:

```
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "4.2.x-dev"
},
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/flyingL123/framework"
    } 
]
```

When I run `composer update laravel/framework`, I get the following error:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework 4.2.x-dev
    - Conclusion: remove symfony/browser-kit v2.5.11
    - Installation request for laravel/framework 4.2.x-dev -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[4.2.x-dev].
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/browser-kit v2.5.11
    - laravel/framework 4.2.x-dev requires symfony/browser-kit 2.7.* -> satisfiable by symfony/browser-kit[v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.10, v2.7.11, v2.7.12, v2.7.13, v2.7.14, v2.7.15, v2.7.16, v2.7.17, v2.7.18, v2.7.19, v2.7.2, v2.7.20, v2.7.3, v2.7.4, v2.7.5, v2.7.6, v2.7.7, v2.7.8, v2.7.9].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/browser-kit[v2.7.0, v2.5.11].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/browser-kit[v2.7.1, v2.5.11].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/browser-kit[v2.7.10, v2.5.11].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/browser-kit[v2.7.11, v2.5.11].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/browser-kit[v2.7.12, v2.5.11].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/browser-kit[v2.7.13, v2.5.11].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/browser-kit[v2.7.14, v2.5.11].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/browser-kit[v2.7.15, v2.5.11].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/browser-kit[v2.7.16, v2.5.11].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/browser-kit[v2.7.17, v2.5.11].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/browser-kit[v2.7.18, v2.5.11].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/browser-kit[v2.7.19, v2.5.11].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/browser-kit[v2.7.2, v2.5.11].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/browser-kit[v2.7.20, v2.5.11].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/browser-kit[v2.7.3, v2.5.11].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/browser-kit[v2.7.4, v2.5.11].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/browser-kit[v2.7.5, v2.5.11].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/browser-kit[v2.7.6, v2.5.11].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/browser-kit[v2.7.7, v2.5.11].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/browser-kit[v2.7.8, v2.5.11].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/browser-kit[v2.7.9, v2.5.11].
    - Installation request for symfony/browser-kit (locked at v2.5.11) -> satisfiable by symfony/browser-kit[v2.5.11].
```

If I put composer.json back to it's original state, with:

```
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "4.2.*@dev"
}
```

Everything installs fine as expected. Why is my forked version not installing correctly? The only thing I changed was a few lines in one of the Eloquent files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have fixed it by running `composer update laravel/framework --with-dependencies`.

My best guess is that `--with-dependencies` ensured the frameworks dependencies were uninstalled then reinstalled with the right versions. I'm not sure why that was necessary but it seems to be working.